# Refence an object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please how do i reference (to change or delete) a particular object in an array of objects e.g

```
var myArray = [ {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4} ]


//initial state for number set as an array
state = {
  number: []
}

//a function which runs any time a button called create is clicked
increment = () => {
  this.setState({
    numbers: [...this.state.number, {
      id: Date.now()
    }],
  })
}
//the array looks like this: number=[{id:53432},{id:34534},{id:434553}]

//the array is passed on to a component using the map function
{
  this.state.numbers.map(number => < Section key = {
        number.id
      }
      />)}
```

In the `Section` component, i have a button associated with each field of the array. 
How do i reference the particular object when i click on the button? For instance, a function to log the id of the object inside the array whose button has been pressed

Comment: Suggest you study some basic *"todo"* app examples/tutorials that can easily be found all over the web. The functionality you are asking about will be in all of them. Stackoverflow really isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service as outlined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [ {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4} ]
handleClick(id){
    console.log('clicked id is', id);
}
myArray.map((item) => {
    <Button onClick={ () => this.handleClick(item.id)} />
})
```

Comment: Thanks Anshul. This gives me an idea of how to go about it